# How to auto renew OpenVPN client certificates using easyRSA

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, openvpn, csr, easy-rsa

I have embedded devices that are located in different cites and connected to my OpenVPN server. I initialize my devices before deploying them and put the certificate/key pair through local network. When the devices go online at the remote site they are connected to my openVPN server via private tunnel. I am using OpenVPN version:2.3.10 with EasyRSA on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Now the certificates are about to expire. How can I renew the certificates on these devices? I am thinking of 2 approaches.

Approach 1) A script on the device checking the validity of the certificate every month or so and when the certificate is about to expire it should send a certificate generation request(a standard https get request or similar). On the server end, only requests coming from private tunnel should be served. A certificate/key with same CN should be generated and transfered to the client.

Problems with apporach 1)

- How should the cert/key pair be transferred securely ? i dont want to exchange clients private key via network.
- The whole process should be automated so i can also not put the key manually.
- How should the cert/key generated on the server? i also dont want the apache web user i.e www-data to have access to my easyRSA folder.

Approach 2)
Generate Private key at the client end (my embedded device). Create a Certificate signing request (CSR) send it to OpenVPN server (which is also my CA). The CA generates a certificate and sends back the client certificate.

Problems with apporach 2)

- How to authenticate CSR ? how can i know that the CSR is coming from my embedded device and not some attacker. The only way that i can assure is, if the CSR is coming from the private tunnel.
- In case if the certificate on my embedded device expires before renewal then the private tunnel would not exist. How can i authenticate CSR in this case?. Any one with CA.crt (CAs public key) can generate a private key and send a CSR to CA.

I think approach 2 seems more reasonable and secure but i dont know the solution to the problems i am facing. I want to know if I have a correct understanding of security? or if there is something I am missing. Also if i go with approach 2, how would the implementation look like? i know the theory but i dont know how to create CSR and send it to CA.  And on CA end how to receive a CSR and generate a cert and send it back.

Answer (score 1):

**Since this is old, how did you solve it?**

My thoughts both use a simple API to drive part of the process:

---

#### Approach 1

This can work if you have your client check the certificate, and if it's due to expire, it can ask for a new certificate. This doesn't need to be a CSR or anything, but instead a private API that can generate a new cert. You need rudimentary logic to authenticate the client before providing the new cert. Back on the client, your script can replace the certificate used to log in.

#### Approach 2)

This might be useful combined with an API. Setup an HTTPS API on your client, with a secret URL, where you can *push* new certificates. If that doesn't work, maybe have a script on your server to allow expired certificates in certain conditions.

---

### Another Note

Don't expire your certificates and instead lean on the revocation mechanism

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I never really solved this I just changed the whole system in a way that devices have a valid certificate for a longer period of time and I separate my CA, My Front end, and back end. before it was all in one place. Also, I found out instead of implementing all this myself there are tools such as OpenCA, OpenXPKI, Dogtag etc. even though I never used these tools but if I had known about them earlier I would have explored this direction.

Comment: Have you ever tried Hashcorp Vault? It can do a lot of those things and act as a secure secret store. Will check out OpenCA etc.